# partial specialize template with template argument

Tags: c++, templates

I have this template

```
template <typename T, size_t maxsiz = 6>
class Array;
```

and i have this adaptor template

```
template <typename T, template <typename> class Container = std::vector>
class Stack;
```

What i want to do is use Array with Stack like so

```
Stack<int, Array> s;
```

However, the default constructor of Array does not fulfill the requirements made by Stack, so i need to specialize Stack for Array.
Ideally, i only want to specialize the ctor of `Stack<T, Array>`, so i can give the inner Array member the right argument at initialization.

i have tried this

```
template <typename T>
class Stack<T, Array>::Stack() : container(0) {  }  // container is the name of the wrapped Container
```

it, however, has problems. First, it wont compile (yeah...), and second, i want to be able to give the Array a different size, something like this

```
Stack<int, Array<int, 13>> stack;
```

or anything functionally equivalent (compile time constant for the size of the array). How would one accomplish this?

**update**

So i've done a bit more digging, and apparently you can't partially specialize a member function without a corresponding partial specialization of the entire class. That explains why my attempt will not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rather than change `Stack` to work with `Array`, you should provide an adapter for `Array` that works with `Stack`:

```
template <typename T>
struct StackArray : Array<T> {
    StackArray()
        : Array<T>(0)
    { }

    // anything else that needs to change here
};
```

That will let you do:

```
Stack<int, StackArray> s;
```

Also, your `Stack` template is incorrect. You cannot use `std::vector` as the default template for `template <typename> class Container` as `std::vector` takes *two* template arguments. It would probably be more useful if you made it:

```
template <typename T, typename Container = std::vector<T>>
struct Stack { .. };
```

As then we could add the `maxsiz` argument to `StackArray` as well and do something like:

```
Stack<int, StackArray<int, 13>> s;
```

This is how [`std::priority_queue`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/priority_queue) and [`std::stack`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/stack) are designed.

Comment: wow, the approach of adapting `Array` for `Stack` is brilliant, why didn't i think of that :) modifing the template signature to take a second type instead of a template is not ideal (because i lose some type safety), but because of `maxsiz` it might be the only way. thanks, ill mark this accepted

Comment: @qweasd: you can still check (with `static_assert` that `Container` is a `T` container, something like `static_assert(std::is_same<T, typename Container::value_type>::value, "Bad type");`)

Answer (score 0):

Just always require an explicit array size and use something like:

```
template <typename T, int N>
class Stack<T, Array<T, N>>::Stack() : Array<T, N> {  }
```

Usage:

```
Stack<int, Array<int>> x;
Stack<int, Array<int, 2>> y;
```

Comment: im not sure whats happening here, is this a constructor specialization or a class specialization? in any case, ive tried it verbatim and modified. it wont compile, because class Stack wants a template template argument, not a type.

Comment: @qweasd It's a class specialization. Does it always have to be a template template argument?

Comment: well, i guess that would be preferrable, because then `Stack<int, vector<double> s` wouldn't compile, which is desirable.